# Remove "," at end of foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

I've created a loop to list a set of meta values. I've been able to apply a class to the last item in the list, but I'd like to remove the "," at the end of the last value. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php $count = count($subcategory); $num = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach ($subcategory as $subcategory): ?>
        <p 
            <?php if($num == $count-1){ ?> 
                class="subcategory-item subcategory-last-item inline-block" 
            <?php } ?> 

            class="inline-block subcategory-item"> <?php echo $subcategory;?>,</p>
    <?php $num++ ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I may be taking an incorrect route by worrying about adding a class to the last item. If I can remove the "," from the last item I'll be happy.

Comment: `foreach ($subcategory as $subcategory):`. Is this a recursive structure? Could you please give some sample input and expected output.

Comment: you tag this as jquery, but it's being generated serverside...where are you wanting the result at?

Comment: $subcategory = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'subcategory', false);

This is how I'm generating the post_meta. So ($subcategory as $subcategory) is the correct way I've done these loops in the past. 

It is generating a result of Identity,Logo,Print,Website,Branding,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick rewrite which may lead you to a solution:

```
<?php $count = count($subcategories); $num = 0; ?>
<?php $classes = 'inline-block subcategory-item'; ?>
<?php foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory): ?>
    <p class="<?=$classes.($num==$count-1?' subcategory-last-item':'')?>">
        <?php echo $subcategory;?>
        <?php if ($num<$count-1): ?>
            ,
        <?php endif; ?>
    </p>
    <?php $num++ ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```